# ElasticSearch admin user is unauthorized to access jdbc river plugin

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river, elasticsearch-shield

Within ElasticSearch, I configured jdbc river plugin, it works before, after configured shield and assigned with admin user, the ElasticSearch is secured and able to access by TransportClient, but when I run river plugin script, I got the following exception:

```
pool-3-thread-1] ERROR river.jdbc.RiverPipeline - action [org.xbib.elasticsearch.action.river.jdbc.state.get] is unauthorized for user [ddtuser]
    org.elasticsearch.shield.authz.AuthorizationException: action [org.xbib.elasticsearch.action.river.jdbc.state.get] is unauthorized for user [ddtuser]
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.authz.InternalAuthorizationService.denial(InternalAuthorizationService.java:247)
```

BTW, I already modified the JDBCFeeder.java, to pass the shield.user into setting, but no luck!

```
Settings clientSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("cluster.name", settings.get("elasticsearch.cluster", "elasticsearch"))
                    .put("shield.user", "ddtuser:*mypassword*")
```